# Laravel 5.5 How to get latest N record When using Many to Many releationships?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I want to get latest ten record from breaking news category. I searched here and web but any solutions doesn't work..

I have `categories`, `posts` and `pivot` tables.

**Category Model:**

```
 public function posts(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
}
```

**Posts Model**

```
 public function categories(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
```

**Controller**

```
  $breaking_news =  Category::where('id',6)->with('posts')->orderBy('id','desc')->take(2)->get();

  return view('frontend.home',compact('breaking_news'));
```

dd($breaking_news) screenshot: https://screenshots.firefox.com/rK9hbBq4pIru1o1s/localhost

Any advice ?

Comment: I add dd screenshoot, still cant figure out, how to do use this data.. Someone can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to limit the `posts` to N instead of the categories. There's 2 ways to do that:

```
 $breaking_news =  Category::where('id',6)->with('posts')->first()->posts->sortBy('id')->take(2); //$breaking_news will be a collection of posts
```

Or

```
 $breaking_news =  Post::whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
       $query->where("id", 6);
 })->orderBy('id','desc')->take(2)->get(); // Also a collection of posts but each post will have a ->categories collection as well.
```

Comment: thank you, but I have one more question, when I tried this data in foreach loop it gives me trying to get property of non-object error. How  can I use incoming data in for each loop (https://hizliresim.com/jQDdYD)

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, this will change the `$breaking_news` to a collection of posts so `foreach($breaking_news as $post)` should work

Comment: it works, thanks for your all, answer and description

Comment: May I ask one more question ? Why we have to use first() ?

Comment: You are querying categories but you only need a single category, `->get` will get you a collection which contains one category but `->first` will return the first result of that collection.